# UIbutton with arguments

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to implement a contact us page where there are few phone numbers, and i want to call the number when the user clicks on them. So i decided to create buttons with the phone number as their title.

For the button click methods i have something like this

```
-(IBAction)numberClicked:(id)sender;
```

For initiation a call i know i can use this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber]]];
```

My question is how should i modify the method so that it can take the phone number(title of te button) as argument.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I used `NSString *phoneNumber=[sender currentTitle];` This worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [sender currentTitle];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber]]];
```

Comment: should not it be 
    NSString *phoneNumber = sender.titleLabel.text;

Comment: yes, if your variable that holds reference to button is 'sender' then you should write sender.

Comment: sorry, missed that you gave method signature - fixed an answer

Comment: Actually that dint work. 
I used NSString *phoneNumber=[sender currentTitle];
This worked :)